# How do I filter by year?

Tags: views, 8

I'm finding a lot of resources for 7 but not much for Drupal 8.

I'm displaying a content type with a date field in a view. I'd like a drop-down that presents users with a list of years for filtering purposes.

When I add that field as a filter I'm presented with two options:

1. A text input date, preferably in machine-readable format
2. An offset from the current date, also text input

Neither of these are very useful in an exposed filter. Is there a way I can filter only on the year using a drop-down?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the most elegant, but I used the following on the date field:

[image: Views date field filter settings]

Answer (score 0):

I think we should use the **regular expression** operator because it is easier to change the year:
[image]

Or you can use [Views year filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_year_filter) module